# How do I convert a CMake semicolon-separated list to newline-separated?

Tags: cmake

E.g:

```
set (txt "Hello" "There" "World")
# TODO
message (txt) # Prints "Hello\nThere\nWorld" (i.e. each list item on a new line
```

What do I put in place of TODO?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

CMake's lists are semicolon-delimited. So `"Hello" "There" "World"` is internally represented as `Hello;There;World`. So a simple solution is to replace semicolons with newlines:

```
string (REPLACE ";" "\n" txt "${txt}")
```

This works in this example, however lets try a more complicated example:

```
set (txt "" [[\;One]] "Two" [[Thre\;eee]] [[Four\\;rrr]])
```

The `[[` `]]` is a raw string so the `\`'s are passed through into CMake's internal representation of the list unchanged. The internal representation is: `;\;One;Two;Thre\;eee;Four\\;rrr`. We'd expect it to print:

```
<blank line>
;One
Two
Thre;eee
Four\\;rrr
```

I'm not actually 100% sure about the `Four\\;rrr` one but I think it is right. Anyway with our naive implementation we actually get this:

```
<blank line>
\
One
Two
Thre\
eee
Four\\
rrr
```

It's because it doesn't know to not convert *actual* semicolons that are escaped. The solution is to use a regex:

```
string (REGEX REPLACE "[^\\\\];" "\\1\n" txt "${txt}")
```

I.e. only replace `;` if it is preceded by a non-`\` character (and put that character in the replacement). The *almost* works, but it doesn't handle the first empty element because the semicolon isn't preceded by anything. The final answer is to allow the start of string too:

```
string (REGEX REPLACE "(^|[^\\\\]);" "\\1\n" txt "${txt}")
```

Oh and the `\\\\` is because one level of escaping is removed by CMake processing the string literal, and another by the regex engine. You could also do this:

```
string (REGEX REPLACE [[(^|[^\\]);]] "\\1\n" txt "${txt}")
```

But I don't think that is clearer.

Maybe there is a simpler method than this but I couldn't find it. Anyway, that, Ladies and Gentlemen, is why you should never use strings as your only type, or do in-band string delimiting. Still, could have been worse - at least they didn't use spaces as a separator like Bash!

Answer (score 3):

I just wanted to add some alternatives I'm seeing just using the fact that [`message()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/message.html) does place a newline at the end by itself:

1. Just using [`for_each()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/foreach.html) to iterate over the list:

   ```
   set (txt "Hello" "There" "World")
   foreach(line IN LISTS txt)
       message("${line}")
   endforeach()
   ```
2. An [`function()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/function.html) based alternative I came up with looks more complicated:

   ```
   function(message_cr line)
       message("${line}")
       if (ARGN)
           message_cr(${ARGN})
       endif()
   endfunction()        

   set(txt "Hello" "There" "World")
   message_cr(${txt})
   ```

---

The more generalized version of those approaches would look like:

1. `for_each()` with strings

   ```
   set(txt "Hello" "There" "World")
   foreach(line IN LISTS txt)
       string(APPEND multiline "${line}\n")
   endforeach() 
   message("${multiline}")
   ```
2. `function()` with strings

   ```
   function(stringify_cr var line)
       if (ARGN)
           stringify_cr(${var} ${ARGN})
       endif()
       set(${var} "${line}\n${${var}}" PARENT_SCOPE)
   endfunction()

   set(txt "Hello" "There" "World")
   stringify_cr(multiline ${txt})
   message(${multiline})
   ```

If you don't like the additional newline at the end add `string(STRIP "${multiline}" multiline)`.